# Ros2_control: How to increase power in angular

Tags: ros-humble, ros2-controllers, skid-steer

My robot is on the heavy side and is driving on carpet. The Ros2_control sends out weak angular speeds and spinning power. How can I increase this? Linear velocity is fine and almost too fast! I'm using the diff_drive controller. I realize that spinning quickly is bad for the Lidar odometry, but at this time, mine won't spin at all! Is there a yaml file setting that controls this?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean be "weak angular speeds and spinning power"? diff_drive controller only does the inverse kinematics from the twist-input to the wheel velocity output. If you need more speed, you have to fix its inputs.

Comment: What I mean is that when I controll the Sabertooth motor controller with my own Python routine, the robot spins and turns with gusto. I have only seen the Diffbot_Drive do it with little power. Perhaps I can change the yaml file to allow angular at 2.0 times power? I already had the joystick yaml file doing linear at 0.7 times power and the angular was at 3.0 times power, but the robot won't spin. (rotate)

Comment: Yes, I got the joystick inputs adjusted and the controller is working well now! I was editing the wrong yaml file for the joystick earlier. Duh. The real test will come when it drives itself autonomously, not from my joystick.Thanks